# SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "x.x.x.x" doesn't work - Apache and DirecAdmin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, firewall, directadmin, setenvif

I have a problem with DirectAdmin and firewall.
The following statement doesn't work:

`SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "x.x.x.x" TRUST=yes`

Apache doesn't respond to above instruction.

The instruction is part of the following whole:

```
Alias /.well-known "/var/www/html/.well-known"


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

ProxyPass /.well-known !
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "111.222.33.123" TRUST=yes
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "111.222.33.223" TRUST=yes
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "111.222.33.114" TRUST=yes
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "111.222.33.223" TRUST=yes
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "111.222.33.115" TRUST=yes
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "111.222.33.234" TRUST=yes
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127.0.0.1" TRUST=yes

ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3001/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3001/"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
```

Apache doesn't respond to `SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "x.x.x.x" TRUST=yes`.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Where exactly are these directives? (It doesn't really make sense to have the mod_rewrite HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the same context as the `Header` directive that sets the STS header, since the STS header should ideally only be set on HTTPS responses.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a firewall/proxy then `Remote_Addr` is likely going to be the IP address of the firewall, not of the client making the connection.

Try checking the [`X-Forwarded-For` HTTP request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) instead for the client's IP address, but note that this can potentially contain multiple (comma separated) IP addresses (the client IP address being the first). For example:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^111\.222\.33\.123\b" TRUST=yes
```

If `X-Forwarded-For` is not set then check for other similar headers in the HTTP request.